# Как вывести параметры вывода TV modx?

Tags: modx

На сайте реализованы категории с помощью TV. Категории сохранены в возможные значения TV.

Подскажите как можно вывести на страницу нужную мне категорию? Использовать getResources? Если да, то какой параметр прописывать?

Comment: Уточните по написанному - вы сохраняете некий список категорий внутри TV как возможные значения, потом выбираете в TV один из вариантов, сохраняете, и хотите получить "нужную категорию" - содержимое категории(ресурсы внутри выбранной категории)?

Comment: да, всё верно. вот как это выглядит: https://ibb.co/61sskHs

вот как я попытался это реализовать с помощью &where, но ничего не вышло. выводится просто список без нужной для меня категории

вот мой код чанка: https://codepen.io/kiskiskit/pen/YzZLXNL

Надеюсь на вашу помощь! Спасибо!

Comment: У вас не вполне верный синтаксис where, это должен быть валидный json-массив, попробуйте написать так: &where=\`{"class:=":"roses","OR:class:=":"middle"}\`

Comment: а всё остальное правильно? сделал как вы сказали, но что-то не получается

Comment: что можете ещё посоветовать для использование фильтрации?

Comment: 1. уберите параметр &depth 2. добавьте &debug=\`1\`, посмотрите в логе MODX SQL вызов, скиньте его сюда

Comment: проверил еще раз, &tvFilters=\`class==roses||class==middle\` должен помочь, where уберите совсем

Comment: да &tvFilters помог решить проблему. спасибо

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно добавить несколько TV, чтобы выводилось корректно
       
         [[!getResources?
    &parents=`2`
     &limit=`0`
     &includeTVs=`avСity, class` 
    &debug=1
    &tpl=`mobileShowCard`
    &tvFilters=`class==roses||class==middle||avCity==true`
]]
сейчас я сделал вот так. правильно ли я сделал?

Comment: в значение tv avСity хранится чекбокс с true